# 1 plot with several lines with a common X axis but unique X and Y values... is this possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to create a graph which shows several smooth lines that are defined by an X and Y value. the problem is that they have to share the X-axis.

Is there a way to efficiently add the other lines to this plot?

[image]

The blue line is the graph made by google sheets. I need to add the red lines. (I photoshopped them in for this example)

Answer (score 0):

- all you need to do is to add more series for **`Y`** axis:

  [image: 0]