# In Google Sheets, I'm having some difficulty getting two curves on the same axis

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm having some difficulty getting two curves on the same axis.

How do I get a set of axis with 2 sets of x,y values on it.

I looked at [1 plot with several lines with a common X axis but unique X and Y values... is this possible?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129977/1-plot-with-several-lines-with-a-common-x-axis-but-unique-x-and-y-values-is-t)

And I tried to go with the suggestion there and I have come up with

[image]

I find it a bit strange, 'cos the legend shows amp as blue and amp2 as red. But the graph only shows a red curve. And the values plotted are (t,amp).  It doesn't have (t2,amp2).

I want it to show (t,amp), and also overlayed on that, (t2,amp2).

I have picked for series(which tells google sheets y axis I suppose), amp and amp2.

I then tried adding this into the "data range" box  "A49:D58,C49:C54" but as you see below, it still only shows one graph.

[image]

Comment: While a image might be helpful, please bear in mind that the post size is a lot smaller that modern screens, so usually will be a better idea to reduce the window size to take screenshots, reduce the "white space", and sometimes split the screenshot in two or more images.

Answer (score 0):

To plot multiple series in a single line chart, there should be only one column for the horizontal axis. In order to achieve this you might have have to interpolate / extrapolate values for each series not having values for a horizontal axis values that other series have them.

Related

- [Plot Multiple Graph in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4923/88163)
- [Same x-axis for multiple graphs in same plot window](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78971/88163)

Reference

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation